# Permanent link to a Nominatim address?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I want to be able to link landmarks from a private database to their respective OSM representations (nodes, ways or relations).

One of the approaches I have seen to get permanent-ish reliable link to something found through Nominatim is:

1. Find it on Nominatim
2. Use the osm_id to download all the tags
3. Make an Overpass link that uses all the tags

Is there a reliable way to do that using only Nominatim? Something like a canonical query that has a good chance of always returning the same object.

Side question: Am I right in assuming that due to the transient nature of maps all I can hope for is "a good chance of always returning the same object", i.e. there is no fool-proof method of linking to the OSM representation of physical objects.

Comment: Correct, at the moment there is no "permanent ID" attached to an OSM object. A OSM ID might change anytime (but should do so only rarely). Creating permanent IDs can be achieved via [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Permanent_ID) or Nominatim on a best-effort basis.